# Getting Image from image field to views.py model

Tags: python, html, django

I am making a social media site in Django. I have a page for making a new post. It has a form with a file field to take an image upload. I want to get the image in views.py to save in the database. In the image variable, a string is getting saved with the name of the image. Also, I don't want to use any external form like forms.py. Here I have also tried request.FILES["image"] but it returned an empty dict.

**Views.py**

```
def newpost(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    image = request.POST.get("image")
    caption = request.POST.get("caption")
    post = Post(Image=image,Caption=caption,Owner=request.user.username)
    post.save()
    return redirect("/")
return render(request,"newpost.html")
```

**newpost.html**

```
    {% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Spark X- New Post</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/newpost.css' %}">

<script class="jsbin" src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'images/favicon123.png'%}" type="image" sizes="16x16" class="favicon">
    <script>
             function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <span class="topband">
            <a href="/"><img src="{% static 'images/back icon.png'%}" class="topicon"></a>
        </span>
        <div class="logoholder">
            <p class="logotext">New Post</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainarea">
        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <input type="file" name="image" id="image" accept="image/*" class="imageUpload" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
            <label for="image"><img src="{% static 'images/camera icon.png' %}" class="cameraIcon" id="blah"></label>
            
            <input type="text" name="caption" placeholder="Caption...   " class="caption">
            <button type="submit" class="submit">Post</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Posts")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    Caption = models.TextField()
```

**Your help will really be appreciated.**

Comment: `upload_to` is a directory under your `MEDIA_ROOT`. Images are not usually stored in a DB - rather you upload them to a specific location and the DB will hold the info about which image to send when you ask for it. If you _really_ want to stre the image in the DB, and not on disk, I think you need `BinaryField` instead of `ImageField`. I personally would not do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352464/django-upload-image-and-show-that-image

Comment: Have you tried request.FILES.get("image")??

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Just used request.FILES["image"] and added  enctype="multipart/form-data" in form and it worked.